# Can't manage to read this file with fscanf

Tags: c

The while loop doesn't work and I don't understand why. It gives me no errors but it doesn't read anything in input.
The content of the file is:

```
4
$11$ pelle 
$2$ pollo 
$333$ palla 
$41$ alla
```

My code:

```
int main()
{
    int v[30],s,i;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen("dizionario.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    fscanf(f,"%d",&s);
    i=0;
    while (fscanf(f,"$%d$",&v[i])==1) {
        i++;
    }

    for (i=0;i<s;i++) {
        printf("%d\n",v[i]);
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The members of the `fscanf()` family of functions don't read lines and then extract the format content as you seem to think.  They read only as much as necessary for satisfying the current format.  You should get one value, 11, in `v[0]`; thereafter, the `fscanf()` call fails, returning 0, and your loop exits.  Your printing loop prints uninitialized values after the first iteration.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works. I just don't understand what the space before first $ does

Comment: The space for the first `$` reads the newline after `pelle`, `pollo`, and `palla` (but not the one after `alla` as the loop finishes before that's attempted).

Comment: Ok everything is clear now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`fgets` could be used to read each line from the file. Then use `sscanf` to get the value from the line.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char line[100];
    int v[30],s,i;
    FILE *f;

    f=fopen("dizionario.txt","r");
    if (f==NULL) {
        printf("Error.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    if ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, f))
    {
        if ( sscanf ( line, "%d", &s) != 1)
        {
            printf ( "first line should have integer\n");
            fclose ( f);
            return 0;
        }
    }
    if ( s > 30)
    {
        s = 30;
    }
    i=0;
    while ( fgets ( line, sizeof line, f))
    {
        if ( sscanf ( line, "$%d", &v[i]) == 1)
        {
            i++;
            if ( i >= s)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    if ( i < s)
    {
        s = i;
    }
    for ( i = 0; i < s; i++) {
        printf ( "%d\n", v[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```